# Remove protocol name from website link

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a list of n number (n is known) of URLs. How can I remove the protocol name from the URL?

Eg : from `https://xyz.com`, I want to fetch `xyz.com` part only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using GNU grep and PCRE matching,

```bsh
grep -oP 'https://\K\S+' file
```

That outputs the non-spaces following "https://"

Comment: Thank you it worked :)

Comment: Yes this will also work :)

Comment: If you want to do that, use `'(http|https)://...'` -- `[http,https]://...` means "an h or a t or a p or an s or a comma followed by colon slash slash. More succinctly, use `https?://...` which means "http followed optionally by an s followed by colon slash slash"

Comment: Sorry about that!  The `(http|https)://...` actually works better where I tested the `[ ]` and it returned all with h, t or p in them regardless of where they were in the beginning of the line.  It was giving me a false positive because that was all I had in my file.  I stand corrected.  =)

Answer (score 5):

How about using [`awk`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html) with `F` option and text redirection?

```bsh
awk -F'^http[s]?://' '{print $2}' fileName > outputFile
```

Or [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) with `i` option

```bsh
sed -i s/'http[s]\?:\/\/'// fileName
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it handles the optional `[s]` in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple awk invocation:

```
$ awk -F// '{print $NF}' fileName
```

`-F` specifies the field separator. `$NF` prints the last field.

You might need to use double quotes around //.

Answer (score 0):

Using [cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html): Works with or without prefix as cut also prints lines without delimeter

```
echo 'https://myserver.com' | cut -d '/' -f 3
# prints myserver.com
```

You can use a loop to run this on multiple lines within a file:

```
for line in $(cat input_file.txt); do
    echo "${line}" | cut -d '/' -f 3
done
```

From "cut" manpage
-f, --fields=LIST
select only these fields;  also print any line that
contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is
specified