# How do I get `abc.xyz.com` from `"127.0.0.1,abc.xyz.com"`?

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk

I have a list in which data is in this format

```
"127.0.0.1,abc.xyz.com"
```

I want to get only `abc.xyz.com` without the IP address and double qoutes. How it can be done?

Comment: I see that you've have used [tag:playonlinux] initially on your [previous post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1270303/816190) too. How these questions are related to PlayOnLinux?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```bsh
sed -i 's/^.*,//; s/\"$//' fileName
```

`^` refers to starting of line and `$` line end.

Using [`awk`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html):

```bsh
awk -F'^.*,|"$' '{print $2}' inputFile > outputFile
```

Comment: I have different lines like : xyz.abc.com vbn.ahg.com 123.bhg.com like these

Comment: So the starting and ending in every line is different

Comment: @DedSec I've only considered the example you mentioned in your post and assumed `,` as the delimiter. You can check the output before overwriting the file by removing `-i` from `sed` and `> outputFile` from `awk`. If that doesn't produce desired result, I'd encourage you to edit your post and provide the possible patterns.

Comment: I am not getting the proper output

Comment: @DedSec Please edit your question and add other possibilities too.

Comment: I have 100 lines 
"127.0.0.1,123.abc.com"
"1270.0.1,456.abc.com"
"127.0.0.1,789.abc.com"
"127.0.0.1,xyz.abc.com"
and so on
@Kulfy

Comment: @DedSec I have retried the commands I mentioned with the above input. [This](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/W86VZdbn57/) is what I got. Isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: @DedSec Please **edit your question** adding the examples and the output you want to get from it.

Answer (score 1):

`Sponge` allows you to construct pipe's that reads and writes to the same file:

```
$ tr -d \" < file | cut -d , -f2 | ifne sponge file
```

Comment: `ifne` is in `moreutils` package which isn't pre-installed.